# How can I recover the lost stashed changes (which were never dropped), when the repository from the GitHub desktop is deleted?

Tags: github, github-desktop

The repository from the GitHub desktop is deleted, where I had few stashed changes which were never dropped. I'm unable to restore them since even the .git folder is lost. But I have logs from past repository when the stashes were created

I've tried using all the git commands but they are not working as there is no .git folder, I need a solution to restore the stashed changes using the logs

Comment: What do you mean by "logs from past repositories"? What exactly do you have? Backups of the previous state of that repo? Another repo that cloned the same? Some subset of the .git folder?

Comment: Stashes only live in your local git repo. You can try using a file recovery tool.